# Propagation speed of solutions to sourced wave equation

Tags: waves, differential-equations

The unsourced wave equation in one dimension reads

\begin{equation}
u_{tt} \left(x,t\right) = c^2 u_{xx} \left(x,t\right) .
\end{equation}

(Here, subscripts indicate derivatives with respect to the indicated coordinates.) We can solve this equation to find plane waves propagating at $c$.

Generalising, the sourced wave equation in one dimension reads

\begin{equation}
u_{tt}\left(x,t\right) = c^2 u_{xx} \left(x,t\right) + s\left(x,t\right),
\end{equation}

for some source function, $s\left(x,t\right)$.

My question is the following: when one solves the sourced wave equation, does one invariably find solutions propagating at $c$? Or, depending upon the form of $s\left(x,t\right)$, are solutions with different propagation speeds possible?

(I am a waves novice, so apologies if this question is very elementary.)

Answer (score 0):

The solution of the equation you present, from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation#Inhomogeneous_wave_equation_in_one_dimension), is:

$$u(x_i,t_i) = \frac{f(x_i + c t_i) + f(x_i - c t_i)}{2} + \frac{1}{2 c}\int^{x_i + c t_i}_{x_i - c t_i} g(x) dx + \frac{1}{2 c}\int^{t_i}_0 \int^{x_i + c \left ( t_i - t \right )}_{x_i - c \left ( t_i - t \right )} s(x,t) dx dt.$$

You can see $c$ plays the same role as in the homogeneous equation (which is the one without the last term). More philosophically, and handwavy, $c$ is the only dimensional constant that lets our math translate from time to space, so it has to come up. In practice, $c$ is typically a value that comes from the material's properties, not the wave's properties, although exceptions may exist (but only in nonlinear waves, I think).